# KafkaPublishRecord_2_0 JAAS config sasl.jaas.config

Tags: security, apache-nifi, sasl

I am trying to update my PublishKafkaRecord_2_0 processor with SASL_SSL properties.

Where can i update sasl.jaas.config properties in the processor ?

1. `sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="${KAFKA_USERNAME}" password="${KAFKA_PASSWORD}";`
2. `sasl.mechanism=PLAIN`

I have already updated other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a user defined property to the processor (the + icon in the top right of the properties). Any user defined properties will be passed through to the Kafka config.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for the quick reply.